# Plotting values against time data, which is in different time limits, in a sigle graph after normalising time data

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, normalization

I have a dataframe which has some values against the time data. Here the time data is in discrete units as int datatype is given in the `Time` column. In this dataframe the time intervals are irregular, describing some event which is given in the `Event` column. And the values that must be plotted are in `Values` column.

```
data = {'Time':[21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
        'Event':[8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
        'Values':[10,15,23,17,18,26,24,30,35,42,44,42,38,36,34,30,27,25,27,24,1,0,2,3,5,26,30,40,42,50]}

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
data_df
```

With the following code, I was able to get the graphs seperated by events against their time values:

```
fig = px.line(data_df, 
              x='Time', 
              y='Values', 
              color='Event',
              facet_col = 'Event',
              facet_col_wrap=1
             )
fig.update_xaxes(matches=None, showticklabels = True)
fig.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Now, I am curious if it is possible to somehow bring these graphs in a single graph with normalised x-axis. Lowerlimit of time value = 0. Upperlimit of timevalue = maximum of time duations of all the events. Basically x-axis should be large enough to accomodate all graphs.

Desired Output:
[image]
The method I can think of is to create another column with normalised `Time` values and then plotting a single graph. Here I am curious to see if that can be avoided. Any information regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: if you want a sub-plot per event, with one unified xaxis, all you have to do is remove `fig.update_xaxes(matches=None, showticklabels = True)` as by default xaxis2 & 3 are defined to match xaxis.  I guess I must be missing something else you would not have coded this line...

Comment: @RobRaymond Thanks for responding. I need that line of code to have the lines in graphs rescaled when I want the sub-graphs. Now I would like a single graph: like one x-axis and one y-axis. In this graph, I would like the values of x (time axis) from 0 to some max value. It will be an overlap of all the sub-graphs in the image, if I have to imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- have used **pandas** to rebase *Time* to be a sequence for each *Event*
- **plotly** is then straight forward

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# fmt: off
data = {'Time':[21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
        'Event':[8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
        'Values':[10,15,23,17,18,26,24,30,35,42,44,42,38,36,34,30,27,25,27,24,1,0,2,3,5,26,30,40,42,50]}
# fmt: on

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

px.line(
    data_df.groupby("Event").apply(lambda d: d.assign(Time=range(1, len(d)+1, 1))),
    x="Time",
    y="Values",
    color="Event",
)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, if I was not clear in my explaination of the problem. The graph I want is like: green, red and blue line starting from the 0 in x-axis and some value in y axis. For example, the red line is starting at 11 seconds, here 11 seconds should be 0 and 20 seconds should correspond to 10. In this way I have all the line one over the other in a single graph with a common 0-max value time axis. In this example, the max value of time axis should be 10 seconds .

Comment: I have added the desired output in the question. Here I have manually overwritten the time values. I am interested in finding a pythonic way to do the same with the Time column.

Comment: understood - updated

Comment: The solution is doing exactly what I wanted. Since I am still learning the usage of groupby and apply methods, let me know if my understanding is correct. In the lambda function, the d values will be different datasets which are grouped-by 'Event' values. Am I making sense?

Comment: that is correct, partition (groupby()) data that belongs to each *Event* and then loop (apply()) applying actions